# Sudoku solver with recursion and backtracking

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

I'm trying to code a sudoku solver with recursion and backtracking. But there are some problems with my code it always return false. I tried to debug, it calls next(int row, int col) method up to second row, sixth column and then it stops and backtracking starts. The problem is that the backtracking continues till first cell in my sudoku game and then it returns false. It doesnt replace the cell numbers with others.

here is my code... have I missed anything?

```java
/** Calls solve for the next cell */
private boolean next(int row, int col) {
    if (col < 8)
        return solve(row, col + 1);
    else
        return solve(row + 1, 0);
}

public boolean solve(int row, int col) {
    if (row > 8) {
        return true;
    }
    if (model[row][col] != 0) {
        if (isSafe(row, col, model[row][col]))
            return next(row, col);
    }
    for (int value = 1; value < 10; value++) {
        if (isSafe(row, col, value)) {
            model[row][col] = value;
            return next(row, col);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you don't reset the values anywhere, how could you ever backtrack?

Answer (score 1):

```
return next(row, col);
```

should be

```
if (next(row, col)) {
    return true;
}
```

And the if with == 0 seems to have no purpose.

---

***All done***

Untested but with correct back-tracking: setting the cell again to 0, so it can be filled in again.

```
public boolean solve(int row, int col) {
    if (row > 8) {
        return true;
    }
    if (model[row][col] != 0) {
        // isSafe may be assumed on correct puzzles.
        return isSafe(row, col, model[row][col]))
            && next(row, col);
    }

    for (int value = 1; value < 10; value++) {
        if (isSafe(row, col, value)) {
            model[row][col] = value;
            if (next(row, col)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    model[row][col] = 0;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the comment... I'm still having the same problem... it's still returning false... I changed the ==0  to != 0 ... as there are user inputs in the program to check out too.

Comment: Thank you so much! that was very helpful, now my code is working!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `model[row][col] = 0;` before the return false;

Comment: Thank you alot! That was one of the things I've missed in my code.